# TextMate - Recover unsaved files

Tags: text-editors, textmate

I was stupid and didn't save 2 textmate documents I was working on. Then my computer froze and I had to restart it. Is there any way to get them back? Is there an autosave file somewhere?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In TextMate 2.0 you can find recently opened/edited files in `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Session/`.

Comment: This works. I was even able to find an open file that I forgot to save before I left my desk and pull it down via ssh.

Comment: This also saved me! The answer on this thread is incorrect.

Comment: it appears this no longer works with TextMate 3.

Comment: you are a gentleman and a scholar, this helped me recover hours of unsaved work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So glad this worked! I had no hope at all. @0xF2 I don't see any TextMate 3 on [their official website](https://macromates.com/). The latest version is 2.0.23.

Comment: Not sure what I was looking at... checking now my system has TextMate 1.5.x 8-)

Answer (score -1):

For newer versions of Textmate, you can try quitting Textmate and then re-opening it.  Upon execution, all "untitled" files were opened.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).